# How can I retrieve a Date from FirebaseDatabase and calculate how many minutes/hours/days since the data was stored?

Tags: java, firebase

This is how I currently store time in my Firebase Database

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Then I just save `currentTime` in the database.

When another user retrieves this data, I want to calculate the time relative to the current time, and show for example like in Instagram when you receive a notification; "2 min before", "1 day before", etc.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrettyTime library for that:
https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime

```
    PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
    System.out.println(new Date());
```

Check out the documentation for more info about localization and more customization:
https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/

Comment: Does this library also solve the Time Zone problem ?